# storyboard or rootViewcontroller, which goes first

Tags: ios, objective-c

At the launching phrase of an App, which controller would it use as the rootviewcontroller for it's window (while they both exist)? the one declared in AppDelegate or the one used in Storyboard?

If nothing is declared in AppDelegate, would the App create a UIWindow for it's .window property by default and make the entry viewController in the designated storyboard it's rootViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If nothing added in applicationDidLuanch: delegate Method for creating a new window, so your app create your UIWindow and make the root is the root in your storyboard file, but if you want to create custom starting point, add another storyboard or even a single .xib file as your staring point and let your appDelegate know your starting point.